# How to handle 204 response from ajax request in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-codes, jqxhr

I'm trying to handle a `Status: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` error. I'm using `.fail()` to handle all other errors, but `204` is not handled by this function. While trying `if (jqXHR.status == "204") {alert("error!");}`, the alert is not thrown when a `204` is received.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": bearerToken
    },
}).then(function(response) {
    var obj = response;
    $("#imageid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
    $(".search-results").empty();
    for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
        if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
        }
    }
    //$(".search-results").append("<div class='caption'>" + data.id + "</div><div class='thumbnail'><img width='40' height='40' src='" + data.thumbnailUrl + "'/></img>").css("float", "left");
}).fail(function(data, jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == "204") {
        $(".search-results").empty();
        $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
    }
    $(".search-results").empty();
    $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
    $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: "If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
currently in the user agent's active view."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2xx` is considered success. Your success function should be getting called. Check the status code there.

`jqXHR` is the 3rd argument to the success callback.

Edit: here's code

```
then(function(data, responseText, jqXHR) {
  if(jqXHR.status == 204) alert('no content')
})
```

Comment: How can I specify an alert to the user when `NO CONTENT` is returned in the `.then()` function? The id exists in the system, but there is no image, so I get a 204.

Comment: @Matt I told you how, and you still can't figure it out? o_O I edited my answer to add code for you to copy&paste.

Comment: your edit didn't show up until after I commented...o_O

Comment: However, besides the syntax errors, it does not seem to be working.

Comment: The `data` callback breaks the function.

`then(function (responseText, jqXHR) {
            if(jqXHR.status == 204){
                alert("no content");
            }`

is not alerting when I get a 204.

Comment: I've applied it as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/wkbzxw1e/, but it is having no affect on the response.